# SwiftLint cannot exclude the nested files

Tags: swiftlint

I try to exclude all the unit test files. But it does not work. Does SwiftLint support nested exclude?

```
  - Pods
  - Carthage
  - ".*Tests.swift"
# Errors
force_try: warning #All errors occur in Nimble pod, this can be ignored
force_cast:
  severity: warning
  excluded:
    - "*Tests.swift"
```

Comment: What are you trying to exclude, `.*Tests.swift` is not a path but a filename pattern? What about just "Tests" or whatever your root folder for test files is called?

Comment: My project does not have a path that contains all of the tests files.

Comment: Then you add those paths but in a proper way, look at the documentation for some examples..

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have a lot of path that containing the test files. Is there a way to use the file name pattern?

Comment: I think you need to work with folders when using exclude or include the path when excluding files.

Comment: @benoitcn do you resolve this question? I encounter the same question. How to exclude all tests file?

Comment: @李岡諭 @Joakim Danielson I ended up using the `Find` command to search all the existing .swift files. And format the output of the command by adding the prefix `- ` to each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include folder path in the excluded path section, For nested file workaround, try keeping it in a single folder to exclude the files or mention them in exclude file section.
For Example

```
excluded: # paths to ignore during linting. Takes precedence over `included`.
  - pH7-DriverTests
  - pH7-DriverUITests
  - Pods
```

Example:- project's **Test & UITest** folder name is 'pH7-DriverTest' and 'pH7-DriverUITest' and it contains in source folder.
[image: Project file path]